# Why does the circle in this code snippet lag behind the actual mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and taking JavaScript Training course. The js code is supposed to render a circle at the mouse pointer location and listen for any changes.

```js
const AREA = document.body;
const CIRCLE = document.querySelector('.circle');

function mouseCoordinates(e) {

    var horizontalPosition = e.clientX - 26;
    var verticalPosition= e.clientY - 26;

    // Set horizontal and vertical position.
    CIRCLE.style.left = horizontalPosition + 'px';
    CIRCLE.style.top = verticalPosition + 'px';
}

AREA.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseCoordinates, false);
```

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Initially the mouse pointer stays at the center of the circle, but when I am slightly increasing the speed of mouse movement the circle seems to "lag" behind.

- Why does this happen?
- Is this related to the performance of my system?
- Isn't the listener supposed to run as and when the mouse moves and draw the circle exactly over the current position of the mouse?

Comment: This is the best you'll get. It has nothing to do with your system. Think of it this way: Javascript locates the cursor, moves the circle, and then the OS puts the real cursor with updated data from the mouse over the top. Sadly nothing you can fix AFAIK

Comment: @BastianSpringer But won't this get better if javascript is able to locate it faster, and render the new location as soon as the coordinates update?

Comment: Well, I don't know a better solution to this problem than to accept it like it is. I totally agree with your point, but AFAIK the event fires *as soon as* the browser notices the mouse movement. So, to my knowledge, this is the absolute fastest solution to dragging a circle